# Android Studio - Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio on Elementary OS 0.3 Freya and run it using the terminal. On my first start-up, however, there's an error message shown:

> Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed
>
> Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by
>   incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
>   jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the
>   daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m' Error: Could not create the
>   Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program
>   will exit.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704587/gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionalitye-g-editing-debugging-will-not) and tried all the ways to solve it but to no avail. I did notice that his error was somewhat different from mine and thought that might be why I couldn't solve my problem using the ways suggested.

As I executed the .sh file on my terminal, it printed:

> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m;
>   support was removed in 8.0
>
> (java:5094): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
>   module_path: "pixmap"
>
> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

I'm not sure whether it's related to the error or not. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? I believe they removed PermGen in that version. Try removing the PermSize argument.

Comment: @KevinQiu Yes Kevin. My JDK version is 1.8.0_45. Can you teach me how to remove the PermSize argument? Sorry, android newbie here.

Comment: You could try grepping through your project directory to see where vm arguments are being set.

Comment: Remove `~\.gradle` directory (@home) and restart `AS`. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27516679/483588

Comment: Just a quick note that I had this (for some reason) in my `gradle.properties` file under the `org.gradle.jvmargs` key. Worth checking that. If not, it may also be worth checking if it's somewhere in your project with `grep -r MaxPermSize .`.

Answer (score 43):

In my case I had a line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6408m -XX:MaxPermSize=6408m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

in my `gradle.properties` file in the project structure.

removing `-XX:MaxPermSize=6408m` from that file fixed an issue

Comment: Hey Phate, where did you have this line?

Comment: Hey, what do you mean? Just like the answer says, search for gradle.properties file. It was there in my case.

Comment: Well, apparently this is the only solution that works for me. However this needs an explanation.

Comment: Removing that option completely is a bad idea. Refer to RedSIght's answer to preserve behavior.

Answer (score 34):

`-XX:MaxPermSize` was deprecated in JDK 8, marked as obsolete in JDK 16, and removed in JDK 17. It was superseded by the `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` option.

Change `-XX:MaxPermSize` to `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` solve my problem.

ref:

1. https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4196#issuecomment-1035850918
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#removed-java-options

Answer (score 16):

As it was already said in this thread, [Permanent Generation was removed in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122), which is used in your case. I think, the easiest solution is to remove parameters associated with Permanent Generation during program execution.

Go to the directory where you have Android Studio. Then go to the `bin/` subdirectory. Locate the following files, which contains Java Virtual Machine options:

- `studio.vmoptions`
- `studio64.vmoptions`

Open these files and locate line with `MaxPerSize` parameter. It should look as follows:

`XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Remove this line in both files. I don't know if you are using 32-bit or 64-bit operating system, so you can update both files just in case.

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but I would try it in such situation. In my case, with this option and Java 8, I just get the warning, but Android Studio starts anyway. After removing this parameter, Android Studio still starts, but without warning. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

**EDIT**:

There is another solution for this problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913562/1150795.

Go to **File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > JDK location** and check the path.

In case of Ubuntu Linux, we can set `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` as default JDK if we are using Oracle JVM. JDK 7 is the safest option for Android.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the JDK 7 option is no longer possible, or at least feasible for the average developer, but Android Studio has not updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case opening `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/monitor.ini` and removing

`XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

from it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I've solved this problem, I install Oracle JDK 9 when android studio runs on JDK 6 or JDK 7 (if I'm not mistaken).
so I uninstalled Oracle JDK 9, then download and install the JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS the following clause in **./gradlew** injects this option:

```
# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock
if $darwin; then
  GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
fi
```

This file can be edited by hand after the project has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i was able to solve it by adding this directly in the terminal

export JAVA_VERSION=1.8

and then try the