# Java 17 with Maven Wrapper results in Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-17, maven-wrapper

I use [OpenJDK 17](https://jdk.java.net/17/) with Maven Wrapper 3.8.2 from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) (Maven project, JAR packaging, Java 17, Spring Boot 2.6.0). No additional dependencies.

> ```
> user@DESKTOP-U2OU5HG MINGW64 /c/Projects/my-project (master)
> $ java -version
> openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
> ```

Upon running any of `./mvnw.cmd -version` or `./mvnw.cmd clean install`, I always get the following message:

> ```
> Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> ```

Switching to [OpenJDK 16.0.2](https://jdk.java.net/16/) resolves the issue, however, I need to work with Java 17.

How to get it run? There is nowhere `MaxPermSize=512m` set.

Comment: It's possible that it came from `.mvn/jvm.config`.

Comment: It is set _somewhere_. Consider searching all your files

Comment: Isn't this answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112412/unrecognized-vm-option-maxpermsize-512m-when-running-zeppelin . After Java9 it seems `MaxPermSize=512m` is removed.

Comment: @JoachimSauer There is no `.mvn/jvm.config` file. Only `wrapper` folder.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: The only thing I switch is the home folder for Java 16 and 17 respectively. There is nothing set in my project as it is nearly empty and using downloaded Maven Wrapper.

Comment: Yes.  The newer JVM does not like a command option which comes from somewhere. You may want to single step your mvnw script.

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa even Java 8 does not support this option.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Indeed `-XX:MaxPermSize=size` is labelled as follows according to Java® Development Kit Version 16/17 Tool Specifications (see the links):

- For Java 16 it is [**obsolete**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/java.html#obsolete-java-options).
- For Java 17 it is [**removed**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#removed-java-options).

The Maven Wrapper in the `mvnw.cmd` script, however, aside from the required `JAVA_HOME`, uses also a bunch of *optional* environment variables such as `M2_HOME` and these starting with `MAVEN_` prefix.

The important one is `MAVEN_OPTS` where such a removed Java option can appear causing the inability to start the JVM on the newer version. In my case, I had something like:

```bash
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

The solution is either to remove the option from the environment variables or add this line to the Maven Wrapper script to override the `MAVEN_OPTS` value, In the minimal form:

```bash
MAVEN_OPTS=
```

Comment: for me (using Java 17), removing `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` in pom.xml surefire configuration (`<argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>`), leaving me with `<argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m</argLine>`, fixed my issues.

Comment: @svassr Yes, your case is luckily discoverable using the full-text search in the IDE. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `MaxMetaspaceSize` in place of `MaxPermSize` and `MetaspaceSize` in place of `PermSize` in jdk17.

Refer to : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, You can add to the command line which starts your app a flag `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions`.

In this case, JVM will ignore all unrecognized flags.

Comment: This really helped me out when I had issues with testng.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to ignore unsupported flags, though thanks for this option.