# Unable to Access Jar File When Running Akka

Tags: akka

I am using the tutorial provided at this link: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/index.html#running-the-example

It is a very basic tutorial on how to run a Hello World program using commands in Akka. I downloaded and extracted the zip file, navigated to the folder in the command prompt, and ran the sbt.bat command, but I get this dialogue as a result:

**C:\akka-quickstart-scala>.\sbt-dist\bin\sbt.bat
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\akka-quickstart-scala\sbt-dist\bin\java9-rt-export.jar
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\akka-quickstart-scala\sbt-dist\bin\java9-rt-export.jar
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=256m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.**

I am a university student taking a distributed operating systems class for context. Everyone else in the class got it to work except me. The professor couldn't even figure out why it wasn't running on my machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try installing a different JDK version? maybe try installing OpenJDK 11
https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the project is using jvm setting that was removed from java 9. So you could try downgrading java version on your machine to java 8

[Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' when running Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112412/unrecognized-vm-option-maxpermsize-512m-when-running-zeppelin)

Comment: Agreed that this is the likely issue. Note that the docs do specify that JDK 8 is a requirement.

Comment: Thank you! Downgrading to JDK 8 fixed the issue.